# IvyDe Eclipse plugin - how to exclude jar files

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ivyde

I set up IVY with Ant and able to build a spring mvc project. I have configurations such as provided, compile, test, runtime etc and setup classpath as needed in build.xml for various tasks, ear file, unit test etc.

However I recently installed IvyDE plugin to manage classpath to automate everything from eclipse IDE. provided jar files are app server specific and i don't want them to be included in the classpath of eclipse. Is there a way to not include some dependencies (jar files) with certain conf.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the Ivy configuration you want in Eclipse is the "runtime" one. Then go into the configuration of the classpath container in Eclipse and select the appropriate Ivy configuration in the suggested list.

See the online documentation:

- http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/cpc/edit.html
- http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/images/ivy_file_def.jpg